# How to speed up Krita?

Tags: windows-10, krita

I'm trying Krita for the first time (version 3.0), following this Bob Ross tutorial with some custom brushes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw9LwWcNSgY

Krita is very laggy and slow - such that I can't draw properly.

**Is there anything I can do to fix this?**

I found this topic: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=281&t=125170 but can't logon to post because the KDE forum is unusable - tells me "Error 403 Client rejected by automatic spammer detection system"

My pc is Windows 10, 16GB RAM, i5 3Gz.

My image is 18" x 20", 300 dpi.  At 100 dpi it's slighty better, but the mouse still keeps jumping around unpredictably after I've moved it.

Comment: Hi @Richard, welcome to GDSE. We're not really tech people here, being desingers, so I'm not 100% sure we're going to be able to help you. The forum you linked to doesn't provide much help, except maybe try to disable OpenGL.

Comment: Oh wow. That actually makes a big improvement, thanks. For other people wanting to know how: Settings - Configure - Display - Uncheck OpenGl

Comment: I added our comments as an answer. If you could please accept it, so the system can mark this question as done (unanswered questions keep getting bumped to the top of the front page you see) and I'll get some rep for helping you.

Comment: @Richard I'm new to Krita myself, though I notice that disabling Instant Preview Mode can reduce some lag with some brush strokes. You can disable it by unticking the option under *View>Instant Preview Mode*. I think this mode exists for working on very large illustrations though it may be better to disable it depending on what sort of brushes you're using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the conversation you linked to, disabling OpenGL can cause significant speed improvements in some systems.

Go to Settings > Configure > Display > Uncheck OpenGl

Comment: That did indeed provide an immediate decrease in lag for me (Windows 7, Krita 2.9.9). Thanks!

Comment: Although, upgrading to 3.0 got rid of the lag without having to disable OpenGL. :-)

Comment: I can confirm that disabling OpenGL fixed the sluggishness on Krita 3.3.3 64-bit on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Im my case, Krita was responding very poorly until I unchecked OpenGL, as PieBie also mentions in his answer; once unchecked, however, I was able to move the screen around but the brushes weren't registering when I tried to draw. So I fiddled around and found another setting that was decisive for me:

**increase the memory limit** under Settings > Configure Krita > Performance

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had the opposite experience with a Surface Go 2. The Go has a pretty basic cpu but a surprisingly good graphics card that seems to handle OpenGL (and other gpu-intensive software) surprisingly well. So the Go has maybe the opposite situation of many other Windows computers that have more powerful cpu's but just integrated or basic graphics.

Krita installed using "Direct 3D 11 via Angle" for the Display setting, and was unusably laggy. Switching to OpenGL made a world of difference. So I guess it depends on the graphics card in your computer which works best.